Access dropbox file - The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found
I'm new in this type of access. I wrote this code but i have the error in objet to recover the list of files in dropbox.
Dim token As String
token = "sl.B6........."
Dim _command As String
_command = "https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/list_folder"
Dim Request As HttpWebRequest
Request = HttpWebRequest.Create(_command)
Request.Method = "GET"
Request.KeepAlive = True
Request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
Request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36"
Request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " & token)
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
Dim Response As HttpWebResponse = Request.GetResponse()

i try to change the type of security but i always the same error.

i changed the content type with "application/json "and i have this error : "Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream."

[Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-API-Support-Feedback/Access-dropbox-file-Authentication-failed-because-the-remote/td-p/789012 ]

As @Greg said, you must use POST (instead of GET) and pass the path inside the body, probably using Request.GetRequestStream(). See the documentation.
